# How can I check if the level is loaded in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've started learning C# and Unity3D this year and I've come across a problem. I'm loading a new level and the player object gets initialized before the the level has finished loading.

I think I only need to check whether the level is loaded or not before initializing the object. I don't know if I could use LoadLevelAsync. I'm using Unity3D Personal Edition.

My current code:

MasterClient.cs

```cs
void Update(){
    if(SceneUpdateRequired)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(SceneUpdateID);
        if (Application.isLoadingLevel == false)
        {              
            SceneUpdateRequired = false;
            SceneUpdateCompleted = true;
        }
    }
}

void CharacterLoginUpdate(){
    if (SceneUpdateCompleted == true)
    { 
        GameObject networkPlayerObj = (GameObject)Instantiate(NPlayerObj, PlayerLoginUpdatePosition, PlayerLoginUpdateRotation);
        NPlayer networkPlayer = networkPlayerObj.GetComponent<NPlayer>();
        networkPlayer.UpdatePlayerInstantiateCompleted(PlayerLoginUpdateNetworkID, PlayerLoginUpdateHP, PlayerLoginUpdateClass, PlayerLoginUpdateLevel, PlayerLoginUpdateName, PlayerLoginUpdatePosition);
        PlayerLoginUpdateRequired = false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Does your current code not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is your are loading level in update where if you dont control the task with booleans you are going to end up  with big problems.
your update code should be as follows

```
 void Update(){
    if(SceneUpdateRequired)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(SceneUpdateID);
        SceneUpdateRequired = false;        
    }
    if (Application.isLoadingLevel == false)
    {              
        SceneUpdateRequired = false;
        SceneUpdateCompleted = true;
    }
 }
```

This way the scene code will try to load level only when you request it to and not every time in update loop as loading levels is heavy.

Another thing is you might encounter one more problem if you need to use 
 **SceneUpdateRequired,SceneUpdateCompleted** variables somewhere else the

```
if (Application.isLoadingLevel == false)
{              
    SceneUpdateRequired = false;
    SceneUpdateCompleted = true;
}
```

the above part which is in update loop will reset the variables everytime whenever its not loading the level. To prevent this you will have to introduce another boolean flag to stop its update happening everytime. So your code will end up looking like this if you want to prevent everyframe update

```
void Update() {
    if(SceneUpdateRequired){
        Application.LoadLevel(SceneUpdateID);
        SceneUpdateRequired = false;
    }
    if (Application.isLoadingLevel == false && StartCheckingLoadLevel){ 
        SceneUpdateRequired = false;
        SceneUpdateCompleted = true;
        StartCheckingLoadLevel = false;
    }
}

void StartLoad() {
    SceneUpdateRequired = true;
    SceneUpdateCompleted = false; 
    StartCheckingLoadLevel = true;
}

void CharacterLoginUpdate(){
    if (SceneUpdateCompleted == true) {
        Debug.Log("Do Something after load");
    } else {
        Debug.Log("Scene not yet loaded");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, kinda focused on marking it as the answer here. For anyone that visit this after Unity 5, this is obsolete. See https://answers.unity.com/questions/1068801/applicationisloadinglevel-deprecation.html which explains using `SceneManager` and its replacement methods.